# A website using HTML 4 Transitional

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I am using Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18163.

This is what the website source code says

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

The website using DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN has a database that I am uploading data into but the website is losing data after pressing a button which should save it, but it won't save the data, I am losing my inputted data arbitrarily.

Is the code too old for the version of Internet Explorer?
And, is there a fix?

Comment: The source code has 1 line..?

Comment: What other web browsers have you tried? The problem does not occur with these?

Comment: Hi Rudd, I've tried sea monkey, but what else would you suggest, chrome doesn't work with it. It doesn't save. The data is seen but the page is not responsive to clicking in the cells for data entry.

Comment: I've tried sea monkey and chrome, but the browsers are non-responsive to me clicking on the cells. Are there browsers which are compatible with this older code?

Comment: I think the DTD is the least relevant line of "code" you could've possibly shown

Comment: It's not, because it tells you the doc type version.

Comment: I agree with Jaromanda X, the problem is more likely to be found in non-standard JavaScript code or deprecated HTML attributes. Check for [JavaScript errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255006(v=vs.85).aspx). Show the button's event handler code (JavaScript). We may need to see a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).